# Make the background gradient(radial) move on scroll using css and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, radial-gradients

So what I was looking for is a subtle radial gradient background effect which will move from left to right when the page is scrolled, like this site - https://hellonesh.io/ . So when I inspected the code of that site, I found the responsible HTML and CSS for that effect -

**HTML**

```
<body>
<main>

  <div class="bg" style="background-image: radial-gradient(88.33% 60.62% at 100.87% 48.33%, rgb(86, 53, 173) 0%, rgb(20, 9, 78) 100%);"></div>

  <section id="sec-1">
    ...
  </section>
  <section id="sec-2">
    ...
  </section>
  <section id="sec-3">
    ...
  </section>

</main>

<script>

  //  Need help here

</script>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.bg {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

jQuery/js

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    //When a new section(100Vh) comes into view move the radial gradient left to right or right to left
    // completely lost here
    // $('.bg').css({background-image: "radial-gradient()"});
});
```

But I've no idea how to make the radial gradient move in the viewport when scrolled. If it's a plugin please let me know the name. If not then how can I achieve that effect using JavaScript or jQuery? Thanks!

Comment: What are the conditions under which you want to change the position of the bacground? In the site you point to it is done on clicking on an element (the left hand side'list') but you talk about scrolling, in which case you need to add an event listener for the scroll event. Please try some code and add it to your question if you are still stuck.

Comment: Thanks @AHaworth! So you are right in the site I mentioned the effect take place when I click the left side section indicator but also when I scroll and the section changes. I want that exact effect to replicate. And I'm still stuck. Hoping to learn something new today!

Comment: Could you describe exactly what condition(s) will lead to the background being moved - there now seems to be a requirement for it to move when a paricular section comes into view - that is a different thing and you can investigate intersectionObserver to do that. If that is the condition that leads to the required change then let me know.

Comment: Sorry @AHaworth if my description is not clear. Here's what I'm looking for - " whenever I scroll to a new section( which is 100Vh) the radial grad should shift from left to right and then right to left smoothly like that site". Here the "new section" part would be nice but not necessary. I hope I've cleared the confusion this time.

Comment: Hello @AHaworth I've updated the html also. I hope now it's clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this question: how to sense when another section comes into view and when it does how to move the background image depending on which section is now in view.

For the first we can use InterSectionObserver. If we attach the observer to each section, it will get fired when that section comes into (or goes out of, but we aren't interested in that) the viewport.

For the second, this snippet uses a CSS variable --x to say where the background image radial gradient is to have its 'at' x coord set. I don't know what values you want for each section, so this snippet just looks at the id of the section that is in view and calculates the offset just for the demo.

```js
function callback(entries) {
  entries.forEach( entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      let x = 50 * Number(entry.target.id.replace('sec-', '') - 1); //change to whatever you want the x to be for sec-n
      bg.style.setProperty('--x', x + '%');
    }
  });
}

const bg = document.querySelector('.bg');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);

sections.forEach( section => {
  observer.observe(section);  
});
```

```css
.bg { 
    --x: 0;
    --y: 48.33%;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: radial-gradient(88.33% 60.62% at var(--x) var(--y), rgb(86, 53, 173) 0%, rgb(20, 9, 78) 100%);
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>

  <div class="bg"></div>

  <section id="sec-1">
    ...
  </section>
  <section id="sec-2">
    ...
  </section>
  <section id="sec-3">
    ...
  </section>

</main>
```